# How to not stop progress of question if answred wrong

Tags: javascript

i want to know how to make the program to still countinue the progress if the `"Var Option"` is awnsered wrong, I did `alert("The program can only +,-,/..");` but after that i have no idea how make make it go back again to `var Option = prompt("+,-,/?");` and continue the progress without reseting all the progress again.

```js
function test() {
  var One = prompt("First number?");
  var Option = prompt("+,-,/?");
  var Two = prompt("Second number?");
  var Pluse = Number(One) + Number(Two);
  var Minuse = Number(One) - Number(Two);
  var Devaied = Number(One) / Number(Two);

  if (Option == "+") {
    alert(Pluse);
  } else if (Option == "-") {
    alert(Minuse);
  } else if (Option == "/") {
    alert(Devaied);
  } else {
    alert("The program can only +,-,/.. please try again.");
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps use a while loop?

Comment: use `do...while` loop

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding some form of recursion.

```js
function test(prevOne, prevTwo) {
  var One = prevOne !== undefined ? prevOne : prompt("First number?");
  var Option = prompt("+,-,/?");
  var Two = prevTwo !== undefined ? prevTwo : prompt("Second number?");
  var Pluse = Number(One) + Number(Two);
  var Minuse = Number(One) - Number(Two);
  var Devaied = Number(One) / Number(Two);

  if (Option == "+") {
    alert(Pluse);
  } else if (Option == "-") {
    alert(Minuse);
  } else if (Option == "/") {
    alert(Devaied);
  } else {
    test(One, Two)
  }
}
```

What we do is we remember the number input from the previous function call as parameters. If the Option (operator) isn't the right character we call the same function again but since `One` and `Two` are set it only calls `prompt` on `Option`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my answer does what you're asking, it does go back and ask for `Option` again and still holds the previous `One`. Or I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: No, i missunderstood your awnser and then i reread it again sorry for that, but still for some reason its still dosn't save the stored `One` and `Two` and it keeps demanding me to store them again for some reason, i am not sure why tho...

Comment: The term is ["memoize"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization), and that's not what you're doing.

Comment: @Kayoku Hmm not sure why it doesn't work for you. I copied this exact code in the chrome console to test it out and it runs for me.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Yes that was a typo, also - I you're right, I figured that it'd be similar since the functionality has some recursion. I do however see how it can be confusing. Edited

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.

```js
function test() {
  var One = prompt("First number?");
  var Option = prompt("+,-,/?");
  while (['+', '-', '/'].indexOf(Option) === -1) {
    Option = prompt("+,-,/?");
  }
  var Two = prompt("Second number?");
  var Pluse = Number(One) + Number(Two);
  var Minuse = Number(One) - Number(Two);
  var Devaied = Number(One) / Number(Two);

  if (Option == "+") {
    alert(Pluse);
  } else if (Option == "-") {
    alert(Minuse);
  } else if (Option == "/") {
    alert(Devaied);
  } else {
    alert("The program can only +,-,/.. please try again.");
  }
}

test()
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will ask the user for a valid option up to 3 times then throw an exception if it still hasn't received valid input. If you don't pass a maxAttempts parameter to the `tryGetOption` function, it will keep trying indefinitely.

```js
function test() {
  var One = prompt("First number?");
  var Option;

  try {
    Option = tryGetOption("+,-,/", 3);
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err);
    return;
  }

  var Two = prompt("Second number?");
  var Pluse = Number(One) + Number(Two);
  var Minuse = Number(One) - Number(Two);
  var Devaied = Number(One) / Number(Two);
  if (Option == "+") {

    alert(Pluse);
  } else if (Option == "-") {
    alert(Minuse);

  } else if (Option == "/") {
    alert(Devaied);
  }
}

function tryGetOption(inputs, maxAttempts) {
  return (function tryAgain(attempts) {
    if (attempts > maxAttempts) {
      throw new Error("Invalid input");
    }
    var tryAgainText = "";
    if (attempts++ > 1) {
      tryAgainText = "Please try again. "
    }
    var result = prompt(tryAgainText + inputs + "?");
    if (inputs.split("").indexOf(result) < 0) {
      return tryAgain(attempts);
    }
    return result;
  })(1);
}

test();
```